# print average numbers

Tags: java

I am new to java.And so i am practising some questions.But i got stumbled over this.I know i am very close to the right answer and i am thinking of putting a else condition that if it less than 0.it will break.
Tried inserting this here and there but it cannot work.

Write a method named printAverage that accepts a Scanner for the console as a parameter and repeatedly prompts the user for numbers. Once any number less than zero is typed, the average of all non-negative numbers typed is displayed. Display the average as a double, and do not round it. For example, a call to your method might look like this:

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
printAverage(console);
The following is one example log of execution for your method:

Type a number: 7
Type a number: 4
Type a number: 16
Type a number: -4
Average was 9.0
If the first number typed is negative, do not print an average.
```

My attempt:

```
  public static void printAverage(Scanner console){

    int num=0;
    double sum=0;
    double avg=0;
    int counter=0;
    while(num>=0){
   System.out.print("Type a number: ");
     num=console.nextInt();

        if(num>0){
     sum+=num;
     counter++;
    avg=sum/counter;
        }


    }
    System.out.println("Average was " +  avg);


}
```

Sorry.The question was not clear.For example,when i type in 0 0 1 1 -2 as the numbers.I am supposed to get

Type a number: 0
Type a number: 0
Type a number: 1
Type a number: 1
Type a number: -2
Average was 0.5

But i am getting

Type a number: 0
Type a number: 0
Type a number: 1
Type a number: 1
Type a number: -2
Average was 1.0

Comment: Tried entering negative number.But it just wont stop and break off the loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
do {
    System.out.print("Type a number: ");
    num=console.nextInt();
    if (num >= 0) {
        sum+=num;
        counter++;
    }
} while (num >= 0);
if (counter > 0) {
    avg = sum / counter;
    System.out.println("Average was " +  avg);
}
```

Comment: How will you know to use a do while loops first?I am always confused which one to use

Comment: the main difference between `while` and `do while` is that `do while` will be executed at least once.

Answer (score 0):

> i am thinking of putting a else condition that if it less than 0.it
>   will break. Tried inserting this here and there but it cannot work.

If you put the `else` or not will not matter, as the `while()`, is taking care of break out of calculation

and also because of `else` part comes last statement in the loop

Answer (score 0):

To suppress the printing if the first number was negative, just add an `if` around the `System.out.println()`:

```
if (counter > 0) {
    System.out.println("Average was " +  avg);
}
```

Also, there's a bug in the existing `if`, which should be

```
            if(num>=0){
```

Comment: Why do you use counter here?From my understanding,shouldn't it be num?

Comment: @user2179615: You are ignoring zeroes. Change `if(num>0)` to `if(num>=0)`.